# How do I modify the email maximum length to 320 characters?

Tags: 8, emails

I want to overwrite the maximum charcater limit to 320. It is defined in [/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Email.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Email.php/constant/Email%3A%3AEMAIL_MAX_LENGTH/8.2.x)

Can anybody tell me how to overwrite it?

Answer (score 3):

You can using [hook_element_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.2.x).

mymodule.module

```
/*
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_element_info_alter(array &$info) {
  if (!empty($info['email'])) {
    $info['email']['#maxlength'] = 320;
  }
}
```

Flush all caches so hook gets pickedup.

As Neograph734 pointed out, the mail column's VARCHAR length will also have to be increased in the DB.  See [Resizing Fields in Drupal 8 Without Losing Data](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/resizing-fields-drupal-8-without-losing-data) to learn how you can accomplish that.

Comment: Be aware that although this will allow you to enter a value longer than 255 characters. The database definition for the email field (at least on the user) is `varchar(254)`. So you will not be able to store the longer value.

Comment: Also worth noting that the RFC which said email addresses are 320 chars long was wrong - 254 is the right number (256 including `<` and `>`)

Comment: I had tried hook_element_info_alter ,What i want if any new email field is created for a entity , the Max length is database should also be changed ,If i go manually and update the length for testing
 /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Email.php. to 320 ,every new email field created in database also has 320 charcater length

Comment: @namitgarg One should avoid hacking/patching core, but in this particular case since it's a constant, patching the value makes sense. If you use a composer managed site, create a patch and add the patch path to composer so it applies it every time you update Drupal core.

Comment: @No Sssweat, Ya when i suggested to make the change in core, i was told by a colleague that it can be overwritten in custom module,Is there is a way we can overwrite this in a custom module. just asking to be sure before i say go back to him

Comment: Does this answer change the length in the DB when a new email field is crested? If not I'll have to look into it as there appears to be no hook_schema_alter for D8.

Comment: @NoSssweat. Ni it does no change length in database when a new field is created

Comment: @namitgarg its impossible, see [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2451395) and also [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2467521). So the only way is to patch it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be only changed in patching core , there is a patch contributed here
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3177834